# When should #include be used over #include-once?

Tags: include, autoit

According to AutoIt's online reference:

> It is quite common to have the same "#include " line in several of the files included included in a script. If the same file were to be included several times, it is quite likely that this would generate a "Duplicate function" or "Cannot redeclare a Const" error. So when writing a script intended for use as an include file, add #include-once to prevent that file from being included more than once. Note that the #include-once line must be placed at the top of the script and before any other #include lines.
>
> It is not recommended to add a #include-once line to scripts which are not intended to be used as include files within other scripts.

So `#include-once` should not be used in scripts that are not intended to be included in other scripts. Why?

If the benefit of using `#include-once` is to prevent errors triggered by duplicate `#include`, then what is the benefit(s) of using `#include` over `#include-once`?

Answer (score 1):

> "… *what is the benefit(s) of using `#include` over `#include-once`?*"

None; they serve different purposes.

`#include <filename.au3>` includes `filename.au3`. `#include-once` (no parameters) prevents a file containing that directive from being included more than once.

If two different include files contain `#include <FileConstants.au3>` and `FileConstants.au3` contains `#include-once`, then `FileConstants.au3` does not get added again on inclusion of the second file (preventing constant- and function re-declaration errors). Usually every to be separately included file starts with `#include-once`.

> "*So `#include-once` should not be used in scripts that are not intended to be included in other scripts. Why?*"

It serves no purpose. Effects (if any) classify as undocumented behavior (unintended by developers and subject to unannounced changes).

> "*When should `#include` be used over `#include-once?`*"

You *could* use `#include` to execute code from another file at a certain (or multiple) other location(s) from within a file.